# Simplify $f\Big(\text{argmax}_{y\in \mathcal{Y}} \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(y,x) g(x) dx, x\Big)$

Tags: integration, maxima-minima

Take:

- a function $f:\mathcal{Y}\times \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathcal{Y}$ is finite
- a function $g:  \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Fix $x\in \mathcal{X}$ and consider
$$
(1)\quad f\Big(\text{argmax}_{y\in \mathcal{Y}} \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(y,t) g(t) dt,\text{ } x\Big)
$$

**Question:** Is there a way to simplify (1) by bringing the maximisation problem and/or integral in front of $f(\dots)$?

**Comments:**  Consider
$$
f\Big(\text{argmax}_{y\in \mathcal{Y}}  f(y,x) , \text{ }  x\Big)
$$
This is equal to
$$
\max_{y\in \mathcal{Y}} f(y,x)
$$
I wonder if something similar applies to (1).

Comment: $(1)$ is confusing.  $x$ is the dummy variable in the integral, but $x$ also appears outside the integral.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited it.

Comment: Consider that $ h(y) = \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(y,t) g(t) dt $ is only a function of $y$ and thus adheres to the rule from your comments

Comment: Can I thus conclude $$f\Big(\text{argmax}_{y\in \mathcal{Y}} \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(y,t) g(t) dt,\text{ } x\Big)=\max_{y\in \mathcal{Y}} f(h(y), x)$$ where $$h(y)\equiv \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(y,t)g(t) dt$$

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the analog is:
$$
\int_{\mathcal X}f\Big(\operatorname{argmax}_{y\in \mathcal{Y}} \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(y,t) g(t) dt,\; x\Big)\;dx
=
\max_{y\in \mathcal{Y}} \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(y,t) g(t) dt
$$

Comment: I think it is wrong because the RHS does not depend on $x$.